# Laravel- Search for an ID in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I'm making a property sales site. A property can be a house, an apartment, a shop, etc....

I have this relations:

Models: //Properties

```
class Imovel extends Model...

public function moradia(){
    return $this->hasOne(Moradia::class);
}

public function apartamento(){
    return $this->hasOne(Apartamento::class);
}
```

//Apartment

```
 public function imovel(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Imovel::class);
}
```

//House

```
 public function imovel(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Imovel::class);
}
```

Migrations:

//Property

```
Schema::create('imoveis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('tipoImovel_id');
            $table->string('finalidade',20);
            $table->string('titulo',100);
            $table->date('data')->nullable();
            $table->integer('concelho_id');
            $table->string('freguesia',50);
            $table->string('rua',150);
            $table->decimal('long', 10, 7)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 7)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('destaque');
            $table->boolean('estado')->default(true);
            $table->string('descricao',500);
            $table->string('preco',40);
            $table->integer('empresa_id')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
```

//house

```
Schema::create('moradias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('imovel_id');
            $table->integer('nrPisosConstrucao');
            $table->integer('nrWcs');
            $table->integer('areaConstrucao');
            $table->integer('areaTerreno');
            $table->smallInteger('anoConstrucao');
            $table->timestamps();
```

//apartment

```
  Schema::create('apartamentos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('imovel_id');
            $table->integer('nrQuartos');
            $table->integer('nrWcs');
            $table->integer('nrPisosEdifio');            
            $table->integer('areasAcessorias');
            $table->integer('areasHabitacionais');
            $table->smallInteger('anoConstrucao');
            $table->timestamps();
```

My question is: How will I find out if the property is a house, or apartment, or a shop ...?

I have the list of all the properties, to edit how do I? How do I know what kind of property it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if a related record is there in either houses or apartments table. So for example if there are no related record in the houses table you will get null for `$impovel->moradia()`.

Ex:

```
$imovel = App\Imovel::find($id);

if(!is_null($imovel->moradia())) {
    // Property is a house
}
```

**Edit:**

I think you better have column in the properties table -> `property_type`. This can take values 'house', `apartment', 'shop' etc.

This will help in easily selecting only house properties/apartment properties.

Besides you can have one relation method:

```
public function attributes(){
    if($this->type == 'house') {
        return $this->hasOne(Moradia::class);
    }

    if($this->type == 'apartments') {
        return $this->hasOne(Apartamento::class);
    }
}
```

And you can do: `$imovel->attributes()`, this will give the corresponding property attributes.

Comment: My question is : this is how it looks like [link](https://gyazo.com/dde2e2e3fa8fe2227f5cce0fa6d61fad) .                               How can I make the details of the house/Apartment show up when i click in the button.

Comment: Yeah,your edit will probably help me! Thank u, i'll try it and then i'll give u some feedback.

Comment: sorry, 1st time PHP and Laravel :S

Comment: yes, that works. but i have another problem, in the view how do i make the details of a house/apartment shows up?

Comment: you need to have the ui for this. You can show the details either in a popup/modal window.

Comment: yeah i know that, but how do i put the details in the view? i need to know if it is a house or an apartment.     in the list [link](https://gyazo.com/82ff2b15252008ac7902671368869507) to edit the property. how does it know whether it is a house or an apartment? this is why i can't go forward

Comment: do i have to add some new code in PropertyController@show? like if it is a house returns a HouseView, or if it is a apartment returns a apartmentView? something like this?